# web page having same class name in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A 
This web page contains `div class='alternate'` and `alternate1`. How do I parse through all `<tr>` elements having same `class` name using beautiful soup.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('tr', class_='alternate')
namebox2=soup.find('tr', class_='alternate1')

name = name_box.text.strip()
name3=namebox2.text.strip()

print(name)
print(name3)
```

This output only contains first two stock data, but i want all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are finding only the first tag. To find all the `div` you have to use [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

```
for name_box in soup.find_all('tr', class_='alternate'):
    name = name_box.text.strip()
    print(name)

for namebox2 in soup.find_all('tr', class_='alternate1'):
    name3=namebox2.text.strip()
    print(name3)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls), 
 `page = urllib2.urlopen(url)` should be `page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`.

Comment: @RickSarkar did this answer help or solved your problem ?